# How does the swagger ui web jar work in spring project?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger

Below is my swagger related configuration in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is the web config.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.xxxxx"})
@Import(value = {SwaggerConfig.class})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
         // swagger ui configuration
         registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                 .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
         registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                 .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

}
```

I can not understand the below two methods.

```
 registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                 .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
         registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                 .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
```

Below is the swagger ui jar in the classpath, I opened it by 7zip.
[image]

Why the path **classpath:/META-INF/resources/** can direct to files under springfox-swagger-ui-2.5.0.jar? What if there is another jar that contains **/META-INF/resources/** and **/META-INF/resources/webjars**?